# Error while executing basic code in Locust

Tags: locust

from locust import Locust, TaskSet

def login(l):
     print("I am logged In")

def logout(m):
    print("I am logged Out")

class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):

```
task=[login,logout]
```

class User(Locust):
    task_set = UserBehaviour

Error Message---

(venv) C:\pythnprojects\LearnLocustProject\venv\locust_test>locust -f firstlocust.py

[2020-03-11 00:38:57,259] DELLXPS/INFO/locust.main: Starting web monitor at *:8089

[2020-03-11 00:38:57,259] DELLXPS/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 0.11.0

[2020-03-11 00:39:05,581] DELLXPS/INFO/locust.runners: Hatching and swarming 1 clients at the rate 1 clients/s...

[2020-03-11 00:39:05,585] DELLXPS/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\pythnprojects\learnlocustproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\core.py", line 358, in run

```
self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
```

File "c:\pythnprojects\learnlocustproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\core.py", line 419, in get_next_task

```
return random.choice(self.tasks)
```

File "C:\DOWNLOADS\lib\random.py", line 290, in choice

```
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
```

IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

[2020-03-11 00:39:06,582] DELLXPS/INFO/locust.runners: All locusts hatched: User: 1

[2020-03-11 00:39:06,591] DELLXPS/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\pythnprojects\learnlocustproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\core.py", line 358, in run

```
self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
```

File "c:\pythnprojects\learnlocustproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\core.py", line 419, in get_next_task

```
return random.choice(self.tasks)
```

File "C:\DOWNLOADS\lib\random.py", line 290, in choice

```
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
```

IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

[2020-03-11 00:39:07,597] DELLXPS/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\pythnprojects\learnlocustproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\core.py", line 358, in run

```
self.schedule_task(self.get_next_task())
```

File "c:\pythnprojects\learnlocustproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust\core.py", line 419, in get_next_task

```
return random.choice(self.tasks)
```

File "C:\DOWNLOADS\lib\random.py", line 290, in choice

```
raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
```

IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Comment: please format your post, it is impossible to read...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've misspelled `tasks` (it currently seems to say `task`).

Comment: Thanks. In addition to it, in Locust 14.0, wait_time = between(5.0, 9.0) is mandatory, which was I believe was not the case in  earlier versions.